# SSH forwarding signals to remote process

Tags: process, ssh, signals, kill, sigterm

I'm running an ssh command as a background job:

```
ssh -l user server 'sleep 1000' &
```

Lets say that the above returns the process ID: [ssh_pid].

How can I make ssh forward signals to the remote process?

i.e. Supposing that I do: `kill -TERM [ssh_pid]`, then it should forward the TERM signal to the remote process, instead of handling it by itself.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question is examined here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40023/get-ssh-to-forward-signals. There is no great solution. Using that answer, here's a suggestion that works for me:

```
ssh -tt -oLogLevel=quiet server 'stty raw isig; sleep 1000' < /dev/null &
```