# Breaking whole chain of commands in perl through Net::OpenSSH

Tags: perl, ssh, signals, openssh

I have a perl script which is using Net::OpenSSH. At one moment I have following code:

```
$ssh->system(@cmd) or die "Failed to execute command on remote system";
```

For various reasons I might want to kill the command and when I press ^C I'd like to have a whole chain terminated. With above command only the local process is terminated.

After Googleing the problem I found [that I need to allocate pseudo-terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658978/ssh-forwarding-signals-to-remote-process). I tried to use:

```
$ssh->system({tty => 1}, @cmd) or die "Failed to execute command on remote system";
```

Which worked partially - it terminated the remote process but not the local one (and I couldn't find a way to check for error which would distinguish both). I tried the `spawn` as well thinking that blocking signals have something to do with it:

```
my $pid = $ssh->spawn({tty => 1}, @cmd) or die "Failed to execute command on remote system";
waitpid($pid, 0);
die "Failed to execute command on remote system" unless ($? == 0);
```

How to stop everything on ^C or killing the local command?

PS. the command I'm executing is a perl script I have control over if it helps.